# while switching from win10 to ubuntu 18.04 LTS no sound

Tags: drivers, sound, hp, headphones, speakers

Using new release on my laptop is great and all, but when I switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04 the sound is not there from native driver. I looked at the settings and it is not muted! The volume bar jumps while playing music or YouTube, but it is not muted! Ubuntu recognizes the bluetooth and headphones, but not native speakers. I tried settings, tweak-tool, pulse volume control, etc. I have tried safe boot to restore packages and so on.

[image]

Comment: And ... what is your problem?

Comment: can not fix the sound on ubuntu on native drivers....and native speakers...

Comment: What is the problem with the sound?

Comment: whenever i switch between operating systems...to windows and back to ubuntu 18.04 LTS ubuntus sound disapear on native speakers.....it frustrates me a lot to have to put headphones on and not be able to hear sound throu my speakers on my laptop...i have dual boot...ubuntu recocnizes bluetooth and headphones but not my speakers...

Comment: So speakers work on Windows but not Linux?

Comment: So speakers work on Windows but not Linux? If this is the case, then this **is not what your question seems to state whatsoever**. Nowhere did you say that it doesn't work, all you kept saying is that "it is NOT MUTED!". Please [edit] your question to add more information. Please see [ask] for how to ask a good question.